# Парсинг pdf - файлов на c++

Tags: c++, парсер, pdf

Всем доброго времени суток!

На днях получил задание - *написать программу на c++, осуществляющую парсинг пдф файла, которая вытаскивает автора, название и краткую аннотацию из файла* (который подразумевает под собой какую-нибудь статью)

Начал гуглить и яндексить сразу и на всех языках) На наших форумах такие вопросы остаются без ответов.. (надеюсь не в этот раз!), на англоязычных форумах нужной информации тоже не нашёл. В общем, ни как парсить пдф, ни как парсить на с++ - так и не понял...

Если вдруг кто-то поможет разобраться с заданием, объяснит, **как можно парсить текстовые пдф-файлы на с++**  - буду категорически признателен!
(Если кто-то и с заданием поможет - с меня пивко) :)

Comment: на английском ищите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951427/is-there-a-c-library-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-like-pdfbox-for-java, https://blog.aspose.com/2020/04/21/extract-text-from-pdf-programmatically-cpp-pdf-reader-library/#:~:text=Extract%20Text%20from%20PDF%20using%20C%2B%2B&text=PDF%20for%20C%2B%2B%20lets,PdfExtractor-%3EBindPdf()%20function.

Comment: Не знаю как, но исходя  из того, что из себя представляют пдф файлы, думаю, что такая задача из тех, для ответа которого не потребуется написать целый проект

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#C++

Answer (score 1):

С помощью библиотеки `QPDF` например так:

https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <qpdf/QPDF.hh>
#include <qpdf/QPDFPageDocumentHelper.hh>
#include <qpdf/QPDFPageObjectHelper.hh>
#include <qpdf/QUtil.hh>
#include <qpdf/QIntC.hh>

static char const* whoami = 0;

void usage()
{
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << whoami << " filename page-number" << std::endl
          << "Prints a dump of the objects in the content streams"
              << " of the given page." << std::endl
              << "Pages are numbered from 1." << std::endl;
    exit(2);
}

class ParserCallbacks: public QPDFObjectHandle::ParserCallbacks
{
  public:
    virtual ~ParserCallbacks()
    {
    }

    virtual void contentSize(size_t);
    virtual void handleObject(QPDFObjectHandle, size_t offset, size_t length);
    virtual void handleEOF();
};

void
ParserCallbacks::contentSize(size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "content size: " << size << std::endl;
}

void
ParserCallbacks::handleObject(QPDFObjectHandle obj,
                              size_t offset, size_t length)
{
    std::cout << obj.getTypeName() << ", offset=" << offset
              << ", length=" << length << ": ";
    if (obj.isInlineImage())
    {
        std::cout << QUtil::hex_encode(obj.getInlineImageValue()) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << obj.unparse() << std::endl;
    }
}

void
ParserCallbacks::handleEOF()
{
    std::cout << "-EOF-" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    whoami = QUtil::getWhoami(argv[0]);

    // For libtool's sake....
    if (strncmp(whoami, "lt-", 3) == 0)
    {
    whoami += 3;
    }

    if (argc != 3)
    {
    usage();
    }
    char const* filename = argv[1];
    int pageno = QUtil::string_to_int(argv[2]);

    try
    {
    QPDF pdf;
    pdf.processFile(filename);
        std::vector<QPDFPageObjectHelper> pages =
            QPDFPageDocumentHelper(pdf).getAllPages();
        if ((pageno < 1) || (QIntC::to_size(pageno) > pages.size()))
        {
            usage();
        }

        QPDFPageObjectHelper& page = pages.at(QIntC::to_size(pageno-1));
        ParserCallbacks cb;
        page.parsePageContents(&cb);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
    std::cerr << whoami << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
    exit(2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```